# ContentBlockbyId in Free Form does not add ContentBlock

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I'm trying to segment content by looking at preferences.
My @pref variable is being set according to the preference of the subscriber, but content is not added.
I've tried adding the content in 2 different ways, but none of them work.

What should be corrected to make the code referenced here work?
Thank you!

```
<!--Script Blok--><script runat="server" language="ampscript">
var @id, @pref
SET @id = [_subscriberkey]

IF Rowcount(LookupRows("BP_Preferencer", "Subscriber Key",@id, "Preference","PLUSPIGE")) == 1
 THEN
  SET @pref = "plus"
  %%=ContentBlockbyID("8733")=%%
  ContentBlockbyID("8733")
 ELSE
  SET @pref = "normal"
  %%=ContentBlockbyID("8732")=%%
  ContentBlockbyID("8732")
ENDIF
</script>%%=v(@pref)=%%
```

Comment: Have you tried Output(ContentBlockByID())?

Comment: what is the DE field name you're trying to retrieve from LookupRows function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use [**LookupRows()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookuprows/#LookupRows) if you're just checking a single column value.  A simple [**Lookup()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookup/#Lookup) will work.

Also, as [**@MBB**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/26268/mbb) suggested, you might want to utilize the [**Output()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/output/#output) or [**OutputLine()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/outputline/#outputline) functions.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
%%[/* Script Blok <div style="display:none"> */

var @id, @preference, @output
SET @id = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
set @preference = Lookup("BP_Preferencer", "Preference", "Subscriber Key", @id)

if @preference == "PLUSPIGE" then
  set @output = concat("<br>plus")
  set @output = concat(@output,"<br>",ContentBlockbyID("8733"))
else
  set @output = concat("<br>normal")
  set @output = concat(@output,"<br>",ContentBlockbyID("8732"))
endif

output(concat(treatascontent(@output)))

/*</div>*/
]%%
```

Also, save yourself some trouble and include a [**concat()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/concat/#concat) inside the output functions.

The [**treatascontent()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/treatascontent3/#TreatAsContent) function should ensure any links your content area get wrapped.